# Is it possible to insert three numbers into 2 bytes variable?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

For example, I want to store date which contain days, months, years.

- days -> `31`, months -> `12`, years -> `99`.

I want to store `31`, `12`, `99` in one variable and will use shift operators `<<` and `>>` to manipulate it.

**What I tried to do:**

```
short date = 0;
date = 31; // day
date << 5;
date = 12; // month
date << 7;
date = 99; // year
printf("date: %d\n", date >> 15); // print the first value
```

But the result was `0`.
I don't know if the idea itself is possible or not.

Comment: 2 problems: 1) you keep overwriting the date: `date=99` 2) You don't assign the result of the shift operation `date << 7`

Comment: `date << 7;` has no side effect at all.

Comment: 5 bits for day, 4 bits for month, and 7 bits for year, is 16 bits total and could work. But you are allowing 5 bits for the month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do so. I would use an appropriate `union` to mask the value regions:

```
union mydate_struct {
    struct {
        uint16_t day : 5;    // 0 - 31
        uint16_t month : 4;  // 0 - 12
        uint16_t year : 7;   // 0 - 127
    };
    uint16_t date_field;
};
```

This leaves you with a year range from 0 to 127. Your decision, if that's sufficient for your actual use case.

Comment: good way. I was not very clear about the reason to wrap a union for the struct, because I usually saw  lots of case to use struct only. Could you give some tips? thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that the layout and size of this is implementation-defined; the data format may not be able to be read and written by a different program (or different build of the same program), and the anonymous struct could be larger than 16 bits.  You could deal with the second problem by doing a static assert that `sizeof(union mydate_struct) == sizeof(uint16_t)`

Comment: It should be 0 to **127**

Comment: Why `uint16_t day : 5` but not `undefined day : 5` ?

Answer (score 5):

You meant `<<=`, not `<<`.

That said, there are two other problems with your code:

- You want an *unsigned* variable; *signed* integers have surprising behavior when shifted. (at least, they do if you are thinking of an integer as being a sequence of bits)
- If you want a 16-bit type, you should use `int16_t` or `uint16_t`, rather than hope that `short` is the right size.

You want something like this

```
static inline uint16_t pack_date(unsigned day, unsigned month, unsigned year)
{
    // Consider inserting some checking here to make sure the numbers
    // are in their expected ranges

    return (day << 11) | (month << 7) | year;
}

static inline uint16_t get_day(uint16_t packed_value)
{
    return packed_value >> 11;
}

static inline uint16_t get_month(uint16_t packed_value)
{
    return (packed_value >> 7) & 0xf;
}

static inline uint16_t get_year(uint16_t packed_value)
{
    return packed_value & 0x7f;
}
```

Comment: He also needs `|=` rather than `=` in two places.

Comment: Thank you, but please I want to maintain ease the code to understand it. I think your code is good but maybe it increased  the complexity for me.

Comment: @LionKing this is as good as you're going to get. The only readability improvement might be to change `0xf` to `(1 << 4) - 1` to emphasize that you're selecting 4 bits; and similar for `0x7F` and `7`

Answer (score 1):

A possible way with minimal modification of your code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
int main()
{
uint16_t date = 0;

date |= 31; // day
date <<= 4;
date |= 12; // month
date <<= 7;
date |= 99; // year

printf("day: %d\n", date>>11); // print the first value(day)
printf("month:%d\n",(date>>7)&0xF);
printf("year:%d\n",date&0x7F);
}
```

The log output of `date` value with `printf("date value:%04x\n",date);`:

> ```
> date value:0000
> date value:001f
> date value:01f0
> date value:01fc
> date value:fe00
> date value:fe63
> day: 31
> month:12
> year:99
> date value:fe63
> ```

But as others said, it's better to use [Bit Field with Struct](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm), like

> ```
> /* define a structure with bit fields */
> struct
> {
>   unsigned int widthValidated : 1;
>   unsigned int heightValidated : 1;
> } status2;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, But why we use `|=` instead `=`, the benefit ?

Comment: Say,  "n = 0x0A00",  (1) if "n |= 0x0B", equals "n = n | 0x0B", the result is: n= 0x0A0B (2) if use "n = 0x0B", it will reset n by assignment, now n = 0x000B. It will lose the original bits information of n.

Comment: @LionKing "|" and "=" are two Operators in C. Briefly, "a |= b;" means "a = a | b" which is a bitwise op in C, After "|" op , you will combine original bits info of "a"with "b". please refer to [Bitwise Operators in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm).    But  "a = b;" which is just a assignment.  After "=" op, a is replaced by b value, you lost any original bits info  of "a"

Comment: Sorry, but How can I print the month, How many bits ? I think `date >> 11`.

Comment: @LionKing your date = {day | month | year}, so generally steps is 1), shift >> n bits 2) and then use bitwise `&` a mask value to retrieve the month value.

Comment: @LionKing I updated my answer to show how to print year/month/day, and added some log info of `date` value to demo its change. Hope it helps.