# Why wrap a struct with a union?

Tags: c, struct

I saw a code snippet from a good answer for [Is it possible to insert three numbers into 2 bytes variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126714/is-it-possible-to-insert-three-numbers-into-2-bytes-variable/31126944#31126944)

> For example, I want to store date which contain days, months, years.
>
> - days -> `31`, months -> `12`, years -> `99`.
>
> I want to store `31`, `12`, `99` in one variable, and will use shift operators `<<` and `>>` to manipulate it.

```
//Quoted: the C code from that answer
    union mydate_struct {
        struct {
            uint16_t day : 5;    // 0 - 31
            uint16_t month : 4;  // 0 - 12
            uint16_t year : 7;   // 0 - 127
        };
        uint16_t date_field;
    };
```

Now, my question is to why wrap the struct with a union? What are the special benefits besides memory related concern?
***PS:*** I know some typical usage to make sure memory size with union.

Because if it is just to use `struct`, it seems more direct and simple to use:

```
   typedef struct {
        uint16_t day : 5;    // 0 - 31
        uint16_t month : 4;  // 0 - 12
        uint16_t year : 7;   // 0 - 127
   } mydate_struct;
```

**Update1:**

Some conclusion about benefits to wrap a union here:

- Can initailize the year, month and day simultaneously

> The advantage of using the union is that give union my_datestruct u;
> you can write u.date_field = 0x3456; and initialize the year, month
> and day fields simultaneously. It is defined by the implementation
> what that does, and different implementations could define it
> differently. There's a modest chance that the year will be 0x56, the
> month 0x08, and the day 0x06 (aka 86-08-06 — century not clearly
> defined); there's also a modest chance that the year will be 0x1A, the
> month 0x02, and the day 0x1A (aka 26-02-26 — century still not clearly
> defined). People have forgotten Y2K already. ----*comment of @Jonathan Leffler*

- You can read/write the whole number at once.(----*comment of @StenSoft*)

Comment: You can read/write the whole number at once.

Comment: In this case I think the OP wanted to use the Y/M/D information as a packed structure and as an integer. Handy way to avoid unpacking-repacking operations so long as the endian doesn't get you.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm thinking you mean C *xor* C++.

Comment: In most cases, the union is used to initialize the structure. Instead of initializing each structure member to `0`, it can be initialized by setting `date_field` to `0`.

Comment: Note that different systems can map the 16 bits of data in the bit fields differently, with the year being in the most significant bits on some systems and in the least significant bits on others.  The C standard explicitly permits this.  In fact, almost everything about bit fields is implementation defined (including whether you're allowed to use bit fields of type `uint16_t` — although I don't know of a C compiler that wouldn't allow them, the standard doesn't require it to be supported).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's worse than that. The C standard also says that setting a union's data via. one member and then reading the data via. a different member is undefined behaviour. For "worst case" if you have a union of 2 ints, and write via. one int and then read via. the other int, it's still undefined behaviour. I wouldn't even be surprised if it's legal for a C compiler to treat `union` as a synonym for `struct` where the members of the union don't share the same memory at all.

Comment: @Brendan: Yes, theoretically.  No, in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `union` means that every part in it will use the same memory, so you can use the first **or** the second part (which can be completely different things). In your case, it´s either the whole struct or the `uint16_t date_field`.

In context of the linked question, the writer intended to use it to convert a struct with two byte size to a two byte integer and vice-versa. Assign something to the struct and read the int value from the same memory. But this is not allowed in C++ and may not work (multitude of reasons...). It´s not possible to arbitrarily switch between what part is used.

Comment: Thanks. And for converting to two bytes and vice-versa, is it better to replace `uint16_t date_field` with `uint8_t date_files[2]`?

Comment: @EricTsui No reading by different field then the union was written is UB. If you want to have defined read you need to use `memcpy`. This of course does not workaround the issue of bit ordering/format.

Answer (score 1):

Union will share the memory among the members variables. So size of a union will be the size of the biggest element of its member variables. That is the reason struct wrapped within the union with variable `uint16_t date_field`;

So user can  use 16 bits of memory for  struct or variable `date_field` to keep the data.

Comment: So, the to keep memory to the size of 16, that is reasonable and is a common aim of union in c. Is there any other benefits to wrap it rather than use struct directly?Thanks.

Comment: @EricTsui  It is a usual practice as per standard

Comment: @EricTsui as concern , if you are creating different types variables inside union, always read the type of variable what we have written

Comment: The advantage of using the union is that give `union my_datestruct u;` you can write `u.date_field = 0x3456;` and initialize the year, month and day fields simultaneously. It is defined by the implementation what that does, and different implementations could define it differently. There's a modest chance that the year will be 0x56, the month 0x08, and the day 0x06 (aka 86-08-06 — century not clearly defined); there's also a modest chance that the year will be 0x1A, the month 0x02, and the day 0x1A (aka 26-02-26 — century still not clearly defined). People have forgotten Y2K already.